# Problema con if anidados en python

Tags: python, condiciones

Hace un par de días empecé un pequeño curso de Python para familiarizarme con el lenguaje, y ya llegue a mi primer problema. Resulta que tenemos que armar nuestra propia red social, y hay un apartado al final donde el programa pregunta si el usuario quiere cambiar algo del perfil. Mi problema es el siguiente:

1. Cada vez que escribo "1", se escriben todos los n1,n2,etc. ademas del mensaje continuar, quiero que cuando escriba "1" ya no me vuelva a repetir el mensaje de continuar
2. Aunque me muestre los mensajes de n1,n2,etc. no me deja editarlos porque sigue en el loop con el mensaje de continuar.

Intente hacerlo con un bool y el resultado fue el mismo, ya no sé que más intentar, por favor ayuda jaja.

El código es el siguiente:

```
while continuar != 0:
   continuar = int(input("¿Desea cambiar algo del Perfil? Presione 1 para seguir o 0 para salir"))

   if continuar == 1:
    n1 = str(print("Para cambiar el nombre, escriba nombre:"))
    n2 = str(print("Para cambiar la edad, escriba edad:"))
    n3 = str(print("Para cambiar la cantidad de amigos, escriba amigos:"))
    n4 = str(print("Para salir, escriba 0:"))

    if n1 == "Nombre" or n1 == "nombre" or n1 == "NOMBRE":
          nombre = input("Nombre:")
          print()
    if n2 == "Edad" or n2 == "edad" or n2 == "EDAD":
          edad = input("Edad:")
          print()
    if n3 == "Amigos" or n3 == "amigos" or n3 == "AMIGOS":
          num_amigos = input("Cantidad de amigos:")
          print()
    if n4 == 0:
             print("Has decidido salir")


    elif continuar == 0:
       print("Has dedicido salir")
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

le hice un par de cambios:

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-

while True:
    continuar = int(input("¿Desea cambiar algo del Perfil? Presione 1 para seguir,    
    0 para salir: "))

if continuar == 1:
    print("""
    Para cambiar el nombre, escriba nombre
    Para cambiar la edad, escriba edad
    Para cambiar la cantidad de amigos, escriba amigos
    Para salir, escriba 0:""")
    opcion= input("Cambiar: ").lower() #para que lea siempre en minúsculas     
    if  opcion == "nombre" :
        nombre = input("Nombre:")
        print()
    elif opcion == "edad":
        edad = input("Edad:")
        print()
    elif opcion == "amigos" :
        num_amigos = input("Cantidad de amigos:")
        print()
    elif opcion == "0":
        print("Has decidido salir")


elif continuar == 0:
    print("Has dedicido salir")
    break
else:print("Opción incorrecta")
```

Comment: ¿Qué cambios le hiciste? Parece que uno es pasar la entrada a minúsculas, y otro es el coding a utf8, pero ¿sólo esos dos cambios son suficientes para solucionar el problema? ¿o es algo más? Lee [answer] y edita tu respuesta para añadir más detalles e información.